# Fluid mechanics - Particular derivative

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differentiation, calculus, magnetohydrodynamics

I've got a problem in MHD where I need to develop the following derivative (where $\vec{B}$ is the magnetic field and $\rho$ the density, both are functions of $(\vec{r},t))$: $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\vec{B}}{\rho} $$
to do so I've used the following 2 approaches that do not give the same results.. so if someone knows why ?

1. Using the particular derivative: $$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\vec{B}}{\rho} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{\vec{B}}{\rho} + (\vec{u} \cdot \vec{\nabla})\frac{\vec{B}}{\rho} = \frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\vec{B} - \frac{\vec{B}}{\rho^2}\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + (\vec{u} \cdot \vec{\nabla})\frac{\vec{B}}{\rho} $$
2. First deriving the terms within the derivative and then using the definition of the particular derivative: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\vec{B}}{\rho}= \frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\vec{B} - \frac{\vec{B}}{\rho^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}\rho}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{\rho}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\vec{B}+ (\vec{u} \cdot \vec{\nabla})\vec{B}\right) - \frac{\vec{B}}{\rho^2}\left(\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} + (\vec{u} \cdot \vec{\nabla})\rho\right)$$

In my opinion the first one is probably false as you cannot use the particular derivative upon a fraction but other than that I do not have any ideas or proofs.

Comment: Is $\frac{d}{dt}$ the material derivative? Anyway, you have a wrong sign in the second parenthesis of method 2., it should be $+(\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla) \rho)$, then the results of method 1. and 2. are equivalent, just use rule of derivative of the quotient to get $(\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla) \frac{\mathbf{b}}{\rho} = \frac{1}{\rho} (\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{b} - \frac{\mathbf{b}}{\rho^2} (\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla) \rho$

Comment: Yes this is the material derivative, and thanks for the error I just edited it. Ok great thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I'm thinking that maybe we should close the question and cancel it, instead of modifying the text of the answer. I guess that it's quite useless for anyone

Comment: What system are you considering that involves terms like $D_t(\mathbf{B}/\rho)$? The induction equation doesn't have densities and the magnetic pressure doesn't have time-derivatives of this value...

Comment: It is just to prove the transport equation for the term $\frac{\vec{B}}{\rho}$, that matter and magnetic are frozen within certain assumptions

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be forgetting the standard [reciprocal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_rule) of calculus,
$$\nabla\frac{1}{\rho(\mathbf{x})}=-\frac{1}{\rho^2(\mathbf{x})}\nabla\rho(\mathbf{x}).$$
Applying this to the last term of the first equation yields,
$$\left(\mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\nabla}\right)\frac{\mathbf{B}}{\rho}=\frac{1}{\rho}\left(\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla\right)\mathbf{B}-\frac{\mathbf{B}}{\rho^2}\left(\mathbf{u}\cdot\nabla\right)\rho$$
which means the two equations are identical.

Comment: Yes the relation I had forgotten was given by basics